# How to transform correctly data.map to Object.keys?

Tags: react-native

I had an array of data. 7 items for which I used data.map. I loaded this array on firebase and now I can't call it like this . Because this is not the Array is already in the Objects.

Question.

How do I do data.map for Objects. Moreover, I need to transfer data. Specifically: id, name , info , latlng. Inside is the ImageCard that should be in the data.map.

Example object:

```
Object {
  "0": Object {
    "id": 0,
    "image": "/images/Stargate.jpg",
    "info": "Stargate is a 1994 science fiction adventure film released through Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer (MGM) and Carolco Pictures..",
    "latlng": Object {
      "latitude": 53.6937,
      "longitude": -336.1968,
    },
    "name": "Stargate",
    "year": "1994",
  },
```

I was advised to use **Object.keys** but still works incorrectly.
Since it was originally:

```
const url =""
```

then:

```
try {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const data = await response.json();

      this.setState({ data });
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
```

in the render(){:

```
const { title, data , label } = this.state;
```

in the return:

```
{data.map(item => (
                    <ImageCard
                      data={item}
                      key={item.id}
                      onPress={() =>
                        navigation.navigate(IMAGEPROFILE, {
                          show: item,
                          onGoBack: this.onGoBack
                        })
                      }
                    />
                  ))}
```

in the ImageCard:

```
const ImageCard = ({ data, onPress }) => {
  const { image, name, year } = data;
```

For the Object.keys I take data like this:

```
firebase
      .database()
      .ref("/events/" )
      .once("value", data => { 
        if(data !== null){
          this.setState({
               data    })
          console.log(data.toJSON())
        }
       })
```

How to correct my example to transform data.map to Object.keys ?

Answer (score 2):

use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and map on the returned array.

> The **Object.keys()** method returns an array of a given object's own property names, in the same order as we get with a normal loop.

```
{
  Object.keys(data).map(item => ( <
    ImageCard data = { item } key = { item.id } onPress = {
      () =>
      navigation.navigate(IMAGEPROFILE, {
        show: item,
        onGoBack: this.onGoBack
      })
    }
    />
  ))
}
```

Comment: ImageCard incorrect data gets.Or rather, he does not load them at all .  Just the shape of the object appears but there is nothing in it. Instead of 7 elements only 3 are loaded.

Comment: Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" | Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `centerElement` supplied to `ListItem`.

Comment: I don't know what's in `ImageCard`, the error comes from there.